# App stuck on annotation view

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview

i am using this code to load image on annotation view in ios but often application crash on  `annotationView.image = img;` line with no error message  can any one helps me ?

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.myqueue", 0);
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
        NSString *url = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[dict valueForKey:@"user_image_thumb"]];
        NSString *trimurl=[url stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:trimurl]]];
        if (img!=nil) {
            annotationView.image = img;
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   if (img) {                                
      annotationView.image = img;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@tuss is right try this:

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.myqueue", 0);
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
    NSString *url = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[dict valueForKey:@"user_image_thumb"]];
    NSString *trimurl=[url stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:trimurl]]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{if (img!=nil) {
        annotationView.image = img;
    }
    });
```

});